# An error occurred during the signature verification. GPG error: http://deb.i2p2

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, gnupg

I need an Indeed help!! 
I ran 
`**"sudo apt-get update"**` 
but I get the following error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.i2p2.no/dists/unstable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried finding solution to this but couldn't find any article or questions on this. I see some similar problems on Internet but not exactly what I have so Please help guys !!

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory.

Apt security uses gpg signed release files to maintain the integrity of the packages you are downloading.

For details on apt security see - https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

Even though it is a Debian page, Ubuntu uses the same features.

So lets look at the error

> An error occurred during the signature verification

there is a problem with gpg signature verification

> The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.

Because of this problem, apt (apt-get) is no longer using the package list from this repository and old lists will be used. Basically update failed for this repo.

> GPG error: http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878164  KEYEXPIRED 1506878180

That is the gpg error. The keys have expired.

See https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c235.html , specifically the bottom section "Updating a key's expiration time"

So you will not be able to use this repository until the maintainers update their key. You can not do this yourself. Contact the people who maintain that repo and ask them to update the gpg keys they use to sign the packages / repository release file.

UPDATE: If you go to  the site http://deb.i2p2.no/

> For Ubuntu, we recommend our PPA instead, and instructions are on geti2p.net

So you should be using the ppa

https://launchpad.net/~i2p-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/i2p

> Adding this PPA to your system
>   You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:i2p-maintainers/i2p to your system's Software Sources. (Read about installing)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i2p-maintainers/i2p
sudo apt-get update
```

And also on the home page

> Please report any problems with the I2P packages on the I2P Bug Tracker

So report the expired keys on their bug trancker - https://trac.i2p2.de/newticket?component=package/debian&owner=killyourtv&cc=killyourtv@mail.i2p